# Find infrared hex code of toshiba wc-l03se

Tags: arduino

I'm a student, in my homework, i have to use arduino to control my air conditioner: Toshiba WC-L03SE.

I know how to use Arduino as a remote, but i don't know the Infrared Hex Code of WC-L03SE, I cannot find it on the internet

So i cannot control my air conditioner

Please help me! and sorry for my bad english

Thank

Comment: [link](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote/blob/master/examples/IRrecvDemo/IRrecvDemo.ino) A good example of a very usable library to read raw codes from IR. See examples of this library.

Comment: Thank jabujavi, i used it and i have new bugs in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450541/how-to-send-complex-infrared-hex-code-in-arduino